# problem with my layout adapter ! beginner android :(

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My log cat:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 
glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, 
data=29KB 
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout(this line problem)
```

My ArticleList

```
package com.mobile.app.starlinerproject

import ApiClient
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Adapter.ArticleListAdapter
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Common.Common
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Common.ItemOffSetDecoration
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Retrofit.ApiService
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import retrofit2.Retrofit


class ArticleList : Fragment() {

    internal var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    internal var apiService:ApiService

    internal lateinit var recycler_view:RecyclerView

    init {
        val retrofit:Retrofit = ApiClient.instance
        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

   /* override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }*/

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
```

my adapterlistarticle

```
package com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.Model.Article
import com.mobile.app.starlinerproject.R


class ArticleListAdapter (internal var context: Context,
internal var articleList:List<Article>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        internal var img_article:ImageView
        internal var title_article:TextView
        //internal var description_article:TextView
        init {
            img_article = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_image)
            title_article = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_title)
           // description_article = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_description)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_article_list_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(context).load(articleList[position].imageId).into(holder.img_article)
        holder.title_article.text = articleList[position].name
        //holder.description_article.text = articleList[position].description
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

}
```

my Layout for show Article List and i create a layout of cardview for adapt the grid !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleList">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/article_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Let’s start by asking: What is your question here?

Comment: Post your fragment code.Also you need to add the LayoutManger to recyclerview to show.

Comment: i have a problem with that E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout @MattiaRighetti

Comment: @RameshKumar i post my layout manager i forget  to check

Comment: This basically happens when RecyclerView doesn't have LayoutManager. LayoutManager helps RecyclerView to arrange the items. By default we have 3 types of LayoutManager 1) LinearLayoutManager, 2) GridLayoutManager, 3) StaggeredLayoutManager  link: [Types of LayoutManager](https://medium.com/@kamalvaid/recyclerview-orientation-types-9d15c3424d85)